# How to localize address of the beginning of the memory area?

Tags: c

I learned C language and I have some questions.

If the best way to find address of the beginning of a memory area is to use pointers?

For example in a few steps

1. I have variable int `a = 1;`
2. I declare pointer to variable a: `int *pointer_a;`
3. I assign variable a to pointer: `pointer_a = a;`
4. Now, I want to print address in memory area:
   `printf("Adress variable a= %p", &pointer_a);`

Am I doing it right?

Comment: `pointer_a = a` should not compile.

Comment: You're printing the address of the pointer, not your variable `a`.

Comment: There is no portable definition of "beginning of memory", and no portable way of finding out where it is located.

Comment: An [mcve] tells more than a thousand words. Read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer_a` should hold memory address of variable `a`, that's what pointers do. as far as pointers are concern `&` is the `address of operator`.

```
pointer_a = &a;
```

and then you can. `printf("Address variable a = %p", pointer_a)`;

you can still directly `printf("Address variable a = %p", &a);`

Comment: Now I understand my mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: `printf("Address variable a = %p", &pointer_a);` does **not** print the address of `a`. It prints the address of the pointer, not the address it points to.

Comment: That might work but printing _the address pointed to by the pointer_ (`"%p", pointer_a`) would be simpler than printing _the address of the content of the address pointed to by the pointer_ (`"%p", &*pointer_a`).

Comment: @SiggiSv form the question i  understand that he wants to print the address of _a_. i answered in that line. already introduce the & operator.